# Android preference, does it have to be unique?

Tags: android

For my  `private static final String PREFS_NAME = "mypref";` does the PREFS_NAME have to be unique for every application? Or can I use the same one over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just has to be unique per app.  Different apps can use the same name without collision.