# Why do file names for Android shared preferences need to be unique?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences):

> When naming your shared preference files, you should use a name that's uniquely identifiable to your app. An easy way to do this is prefix the file name with your application ID.

Why do I need to do that? If I would do this:

```
context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Can anything bad happen from using such a generic file name?

I am aware [of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846146/2956315), which states that multiple apps can use the same file name for shared preferences without collisions. But if that is true, there must be other reasons why the Android documentation tells us to use unique file names. What are those reasons?

Comment: see this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777401/does-sharedpreferences-name-need-to-b